# My spa doesnt signout without refreshing

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, owin

My current project is a fork of the `Durandal.Auth` repo at GitHub ([link](https://github.com/yagopv/DurandalAuth)).

This project is a single page application that uses OWIN Forms authentication in MVC5.

the logout action is like this :

```
[Route("Logout")]
public IHttpActionResult Logout()
{
    Authentication.SignOut(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

    //the id must be null here
    string id = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId();

    return Ok();
}
```

this action is getting the job done AFTER hitting the refresh button in the browser, and never before.
as you can see, the `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId()` must be null because the user is supposed to be logged out. BUT NO ! for some obscure reason `httpContext` believes the user is still logged in.

Questions : why this action behaves like that ? how can I solve this probleme ?

P.S. : I have a javascript layer at the client side witch can block the user from accessing content if hes not logged in. But I really need this action to do the right thing.

Comment: Are you sure the method is hit?

Comment: Yeah sur. The probleme is the cookie, it cant be deleted without redirecting.